# Compile time error in scala Map while I put an object inside value

Tags: scala

I am having one Map containing two Scala objects as value and unique string.

```
val vv = Map("N"-> Nconstant, "M"-> Mconstant)
```

Here the `Nconstant` and `Mconstant` are two Objects having constant values in it. After that, I try to access the constant variable inside that object by passing the key below,

```
val contract = vv("N").contractVal
```

`contractVal` is the variable which has values and is inside both the `Mconstant` and `Nconstant`. 
But IntelliJ is showing

> "Cannot resolve symbol contractVal".

Can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: What is the type of `vv`? - Does `Nconstant` & `Mconstant` share a common interface that define the `contractVal` **method** / **field**?

Comment: I didn't define vv and I let the intelliji to decide its type and both Nconstant, Mconstant doesn't share any common interface.

Comment: If they do not share a common interface, how do you expect this to work? `vv` is probably `Map[String, Any]` **Scala** has a static & strong typesystem, this is not **Python** or **Javascript**, if the compiler can not guarantee things will work, then it will reject your program. What if instead of `"N"` you have typed `"M"` by mistake?

Comment: But I even tried to declare the vv as Map[String, Any], still it throws the error. Now I clear the compile time error by creating a common trait and extending the same in both the objects Mconstant and Nconstant. I declare the contractVal as abstract variable inside the trait. Now I didn't even define the map vv. But it doesn't throw the compile time error. Let me check and update whether it's running or not. Thanks

Comment: That is the point, if they do not share a common trait, then the compiler will infer `Any` _(or `AnyRef`)_. And, since it does not define the `contractVal` **method** / **field** then it fails to compile. By defining and using a common trait, then the map will be of type `Map[String, CommonTrait]` and since common trait does define `contractVal` then it works. That is the basis of subtype polymorphims.

Comment: Ok.  I will try the same. Thanks for the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an addition to Tim's answer, in case you've got types that have a common field but don't have a common type, then you can use **duck typing**:

```
object Nconstant {
  val contractVal = "N"
}

object Mconstant {
  val contractVal = "M"
}

val vv = Map("N"-> Nconstant, "M"-> Mconstant, "X" -> Xconstant)

import scala.language.reflectiveCalls

vv("N").asInstanceOf[{ val contractVal: String }].contractVal //N
```

But beware, it will fail on runtime if N doesn't really have `contractVal` field!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `Nconstant` and `Mconstant` are different types that happen to have the same field `contractVal`. If so, you need to determine which type you have by using `match`:

```
val contract = vv("N") match {
    case n: Nconstant => n.contractVal
    case m: Mconstant => m.contractVal
  }
```

This will throw a `MatchError` if the value is neither `Nconstant` or `Mconstant`.

Comment: Let's say I am having 20 constants with same variable name inside the both objects Mconstant, Nconstant and I am using those constants in my main class at various methods. Then it will be difficult to implement this logic in all the places. I want to access the value as like I mentioned in my question.

Comment: If you want to access them exactly the way that you wrote, you have to make `Nconstant` and `Mconstant` derive from the same trait that has the `contractVal` field and any other fields that you want.

Comment: Yeah.. I am trying the same. Thanks for your time.